# Share a Drive document without notifying user with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am creating a workflow process in Apps Script where a Doc is generated from a template and shared with various users for approval. The Script sends a customised email notifying a user that the document requires their approval but they also receive a second email at each stage in the process from the user whose Drive the document is stored in saying "User has shared a document with you". Is there any way of disabling these alerts? When you share a document manually from your Drive, there is a checkbox option that allows you to choose whether or not the user receives a notification. However, I cannot find a way to disable this notification with Apps Script.

I am using `doc.addEditors(users)` to share the document.

Many Thanks

Comment: Check: [Issue 2829: Ability to disable notifications when using DriveApp addEditor() and addViewer() methods](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2829)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simple solution if you are working with **Google Docs** or **Google SpreadSheets**. You can use **DocumentApp** or **SpreadSheetApp** to share your Docs or SpreadSheets without email notification:

**DocumentApp**

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('124144')
doc.addEditor('example@mail.com').addViewer('example2@mail.com')
```

**SpreadSheetApp**

```
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('124144')
spreadSheet.addEditor('example@mail.com').addViewer('example2@mail.com')
```

However, if you are working with documents that aren't Docs or SpreadSheets, you must share then using **DriveApp** and email notification will be send.

Comment: An excellent solution. Unfortunately, it's not possible to add a commenter via `DocumentApp` or `SpreadsheetApp`... only `DriveApp`. I guess there's no way to add a commenter to something in Drive without also sending them an email (excepting the Drive Advanced Service, of course).

Comment: This solution no longer works, and sharing via `DocumentApp` or `SpreadsheetApp` now sends emails.

Answer (score 22):

Another option would be to use the Drive advanced service (which you should enable in the Resources menu in the Script Editor).

The code used should be

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'writer',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'bob@example.com'
   },
   fileId,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

Comment: Any idea what `fileId` is supposed to be? I can find the file if I try `DriveApp.getFileById("fileID")` but if I try the above code it says `File not found`.

Comment: `fileId` is the 44 characters that appear as part of the URL when you open the file, but I don't think the `Drive.Permissions.insert` function is still available

Comment: @alejandro `Drive.Permissions.insert()` is still available if you enable the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). It is not part of the standard `DriveApp` service.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan make sure you have a valid `fileId` string first. If you still have issues you can try getting the file first `var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)` and then insert a permission replacing `fileId` in the code example with `file.getId()`.

Comment: This is working very well, Thank you. I use this code to share folders which are full of PDFs on the drive. The keyword is the Drive ;)

Comment: @Michael I'm glad it's been helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at the moment. More information about this topic can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2829

A workaround suggested in the comments of the above issue is to use DocsList instead:

> DocsList, SpreadsheetApp and DocumentApp have addEditor and addViewer methods that do not result in notification emails.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point that [Rodrigo Chiong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298083/796963) is still correct in 2024 and it works as expected.

### However, one MUST use Apps Scripts' Drive API Service **v2**.

When selecting the v3, you notice some changes and think it's going to work, however, after making the minor adjustments it just never works and keeps sending the email notifications.

So, go for the **v2** and you're safe.