# change owner and send email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Well, I'm transferring a property of several files and I would like to omit the notification emails, I found some models right here in the library but I can not do it without my code, if someone can help me I'll be grateful

```js
function folderTransfer()
  {
    var pas = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
    var arquivos = pas.getFiles();
    var me = 'email'; /* tirar este e-mail e deixar que seja qualquer prop.*/
    var novoProp = 'email';
  
    var pastas = pas.getFolders();
    while (pastas.hasNext())
    {
      var pasta = pastas.next();
      var pastaID = pasta.getId();
      fileTransfer(pastaID, me, novoProp);
      pasta.setOwner(novoProp);
      pasta.removeEditor(me);
    }
    //Transferir pasta pai para novoProp
    pas.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    pas.setOwner('email');
    pas.removeEditor('email'); 
    
 function fileTransfer(pastaID, prop, novoProp)
  {
    var pasta = DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
    var arquivos = pasta.getFiles();
  
    while (arquivos.hasNext())
    {
      var arquivo = arquivos.next();
      arquivo.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      arquivo.setOwner('email');
      arquivo.removeEditor('email');
     
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189936/share-a-drive-document-without-notifying-user-with-google-apps-script

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what I'm doing wrong, but this example does not work

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the files with `DriveApp`, which forces the notification email (according to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189936/share-a-drive-document-without-notifying-user-with-google-apps-script)). If you know what kind of file it is (doc, sheet, etc), you should open it with the appropriate app (`SpreadsheetApp`, `DocumentApp`, etc) to avoid sending a sharing notification. You would need to check the MIME type to share through the appropriate app.

Here is some untested code that might get closer:

```
while (arquivos.hasNext())
    {
      var arquivo = arquivos.next();
      var type = arquivo.getMimeType();
      if(type == "application/vnd.google-apps.document") {
        DocumentApp.openById(arquivo.getId()).addEditor('email');
      } else if(type == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
        SpreadsheetApp.openById(arquivo.getId()).addEditor('email');
      } //etc...
    }
```

Note that you can only set the owner through `DriveApp`, which means you can *not* remove the email notification. This is the closest you can get through Apps Script.

[More in GAS MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).