# Google Drive Notification In Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wrote a script in Google Apps Script, when I add an editor (a group here) to a Folder Class with email.

[image: Used method image]

The problem it's this method send notification to everyone in this group, can I remove notifications ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share a Drive document without notifying user with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189936/share-a-drive-document-without-notifying-user-with-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Google Advanced Service enabled (Drive API), you can do that :

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    'role': 'writer',
    'type': 'user',
    'value': 'user@email.com'
  }, ClassFile.getId(),
  {
    'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
  });
```

To do this :

**In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services...**

And enable Drive API :

[Enabling Drive API Advanced Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aET1e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using the DriveApp, email notifications are **always on and can not be changed**. Google even has a Feature Request on their [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758249) requesting this - if you give it a star you can let them know more people want this feature.

Edit: 
[The question Sourabh Choraria linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189936/share-a-drive-document-without-notifying-user-with-google-apps-script) also has some great workarounds if you want to use the Drive Advanced Service or if you only need to share specific Docs or Sheets.