# Executing the correct enteries and ignoring the wrong entries(sending email) from a google form by google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form which collects few details and an email-id, however if there is a wrong entry in the email, the script fails and does not execute the next row, it gets stuck there. Now i want the script to ignore the wrong entries and execute for the correct entries.I have my code below.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 5, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];  // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "You have been registered for follwoing events:-";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can add a if condition before this line of code

```
if(valid email address){     
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
else{continue;}
```

to verify if the email id has a valid value or not.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009085/checking-if-an-email-is-valid-in-google-apps-script) approach.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it tells Missing ) after condition. (line 18, file "Code") thas the if conditon part