# Does "Calendar.getName()" function run right? It seems same to "Calendar.getId()"

Tags: google-apps-script

`Calendar.getName()` function returns calendar owner's email address.This behavior is the same as `Calendar.getId()`.
I want to get the calendar owner's display name.
What function should I use?

This is for Google Apps Script.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar

```
Logger.log('calendar.getName() : ' + calendar.getName());
```

I expect the output of `Mizuki Kojima[IT department]`, but the actual output is `mkojima51@example.co.jp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Calendar.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getname) function is working as expected: It returns the display name of the calendar, and in case the calendar is a primary calendar of a user and its name has never been edited, it will be the same as the obtained via [`Calendar.getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getid) (the user's e-mail address).

If what you want is to get the user's name of the calendar owner, you only have one option. Also, this will be assuming that you are using a G Suite account, and that both the one executing the script and the calendar owner are part of the same domain:

1. Get the calendar's id. If it is an e-mail (there are many ways you can do this [verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009085/checking-if-an-email-is-valid-in-google-apps-script)), that means that the owner of it has an account with that same e-mail.
2. Get the user's profile using the G Suite Admin SDK. For that, you will make a call to [Users.get()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user). Afterwards, you can get the name and surname from the profile object returned.